# Residual autocorrelation in Poisson (Neg.Bin) models - Durbin Watson test

Tags: r, autocorrelation, poisson-regression

I am running some Poisson (or Neg.Binomial depending on overdispersion) models and i want to check for residual autocorrelation due to the nature of the data (monthly cases).

I am using R and i am producing correlograms with the use of the "acf" command, where i can check if the autocorrelation for the different lags falls outside the produced confidence intervals. 
On the other hand based on published papers that have done similar studies to mine i see that they have used the Durbin-Watson test to check for presense of first or second order autocorrelation which is of interest here.
In R i have found two commands for this test: the "dwtest" in package lmtest (based on what is called the pan algorithm) and "durbinWatsonTest" in package car which uses bootstrap.
In both these tests the documentation suggests they are used for lm objects which is not the case for my models (nor the published ones).

My question is: Is the D-W test valid to use for residual autocorrelation in Poisson (Neg.Bin) models? Is there some other test for these models?
If the results between the "acf" and the two D-W tests matched i would feel more comfortable but they don't and to my understanding the "acf" is more reliable.